# Is there any difference in meaning between "do one's work" and "do one's work for them"?

Tags: grammar, difference

Could you tell me if there is any difference in meaning between *do one's work* and *do one's work for them*. For example:

> If the teacher finds out Kate **does your homework**, you are in big trouble.
>
> If the teacher finds out Kate **does your homework for you**, you are in big trouble.

Comment: The first implies the second.

Comment: I think that's exactly backwards, Ronald.  If Kate "does my homework for me", she definitely "does my homework" - the second implies the first.  See my example below for a case where the first grammar construction clearly does not imply the second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In context, there is no difference. Both mean exactly the same thing!

But in other contexts, there can be a major difference in /agency/.

Compare:

> That man killed my mother!

> That man killed my mother for me!

In the first case, we would not assume that the speaker wanted their mother killed.  In the second, we would.

So, they are different, in general.

But it is uncommon to have a case in which Kate did my homework for me without my intending that she did so - so we assume that the teacher did not have those cases in mind. So the meaning of the two ends up the same.